# Create a random name generator app

Tags: random, generator

I want to create an android app that will let the user input a certain amount of names into a list which will then randomly output to the screen a random name from the given list.

Comment: Well, good for you.  Get to work on your Android app.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: read the names into a list/array/whatever.

Step 2: pick a number from 0 to sizeOf(list/array/whatever).

Step 3: display the selected name on the screen.

Which step are you having a problem with?  What specifically is your problem?  The more specific you are the more easily we can help you.